# spring boot me trae datos vacios de la bd

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, postman

Estoy realizando una aplicación con spring boot, aún no tengo mucha experiencia con este framework, pero ahora estoy teniendo un problema extraño, y es que, al momento de obtener los datos de la bd postgresql estos están vacíos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi controlador

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(Constants.END_TEST)
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    ITestService testService;
    
    @GetMapping(path = Constants.SEARCH)
    public List<TestSNG> test(){
        return testService.findAll();
    }
    
}
```

Service:

```
public interface ITestService {
    
    public List<TestSNG> findAll();

}
```

Implementacion

```
@Service
public class TestImpl implements ITestService {
    
    @Autowired
    ITestRepository testRepo;

    @Override
    public List<TestSNG> findAll() {
        return testRepo.findAll();
    }
}
```

Repositorio

```
@Repository
public interface ITestRepository extends JpaRepository<TestSNG, Long>{}
```

Entidad

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "test", schema = "smartnewgen")
public class TestSNG implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idtest")
    private Long idTest;
    
    @Column(name = "nombres")
    private String nombres;
    
    @Column(name = "apellidos")
    private String apellidos;
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}
```

Base de datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

applicacion.properties

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres

spring.datasource.username=postgres

spring.datasource.password=

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

Como se soluciona este problema?, debe ser una tontería, pero ya me ha llevado un rato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mi me ocurrió el mismo error, un microservicio me retornó un JSON vacio, comencé a hacer pruebas para encontrar el error, mi problema fué que implememté la dependencia "lombok.Data" que se supone crea los metodos GETTER Y SETTER de manera implicita.
Descubrí que no funciona sin crear manualmente los metodos Getter y Setter, asi que para solucionar el problema implementé los Getter y Setter manualmente (escritos de manera explicita pero generados por el IDE), y todo funcionó.

Nota: Utilizo Java 16. Si a alguien le sucede lo mismo, puede solucionarlo de esta manera.

Nota: Tambien convertí el tipo Iterable<> a tipo List() utilizando el siguiente código:

```
@Autowired
private ObjetoRepository objetoRepositoryX;
    
@Override
public List<Objeto> consultarObjetos() {
        
    List<Objeto> listaObjeto = StreamSupport.stream(        this.objetoRepositoryX.findAll().spliterator(),false)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        return listaObjeto;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Necesitas anotar tu controlador con `@RestController` para que se haga la conversión de tus objetos Java en la respuesta http.

Comment: Mi controlador ya tiene la notación @RestControler, solo olvide agregarla en el código de aquí, ahora si se ve

Answer (score 0):

no está devolviendo vacío. Están los tres objetos, sin ninguna propiedad adentro. Esto se debe a que te faltan los getters en la clase TestSNG para que spring sepa qué serializar.

Saludos!

Comment: Lo que pasa es que para eso uso la librería Lombok, que me hace un getter AND setter de forma automática al igual que el constructor, con la notación @Data que se ve ahí

Comment: Por ahí va el problema, revisa esta pregunta. Tiene el mismo error que vos https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62168522/spring-boot-rest-api-returns-empty-json-used-with-lombok

Comment: por lo que explica en la respuesta, deberías configurar el ide para que use las anotaciones. Si ejecutas el programa desde el jar directo, te funciona?

Comment: tenias razón lombok era el problema, ahora lo instale según la documentación https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-ide, y mi proyecto ya funciona, muchas gracias.